# Using TypeScript Declaration For External JavaScript Library

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I'm not sure if this extreme edge case or something but I cannot seem to find straight forward documentation on how to do this (or I'm just really not understanding what is available):

I am developing an ionic application and as part of that I need to use the  ALKMaps JavaScript library (which is similar to Google Maps API). To do so, I created a local npm module and within that I created a alkmaps.d.ts file as recommended by https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html#objects-with-properties). However, I cannot seem to figure out how to properly import it into my angular code. The same document suggests that using `<reference path=''>` tags is not good but that is the only thing that seems to satisfy the tsc compiler.

My declaration file, alkmaps.d.ts, looks like (inside excluded for brevity):

```
declare namespace ALKMaps {
    export class Map { ... }
    ...
}
```

And I was trying to import it into a file like:

```
import { ALKMaps } from 'alkmaps';  // Error: File '.../alkmaps.d.ts' is not a module
```

I also tried the following but got the same error.

```
import ALKMaps = require('alkmaps');
```

Using the reference tag seems to work within this module but then the project that utilizes this module still throws the "is not a module" error (that might warrant a separate question)

From https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11420 I found the idea of using `export = ALKMaps` or `export as namespace ALKMaps` but adding those to my declaration file resulted in different errors instead.

Can anyone please explain in a straightforward way how to use declaration files representing external JS libraries in a typescript node module?

Comment: `import { ALKMaps } from 'alkmaps'` and `import ALKMaps = require('alkmaps')` do two very different things at runtime. Which did you mean?

Comment: That is an aspect of my limited understanding of node.js then. I tried both of those forms of import (not at the same time of course) to try and rectify the issue with the "not a module" error.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was able to get alkMaps into my Angular 2 app

Insert the script into the index.html file.

Declare an ALKMaps variable in the component that you are adding the map

```
imports .....

declare let ALKMaps : any;
@Component({
   selector: 'show-map',
   templateUrl: 'show-map.component.html'
})

export class ShowMapComponent implements Oninit{
   map : any;

   constructor() {
   }

   ngOnInit() {
      ALKMaps.APIKey = "apiKey";
      this.map = new ALKMaps.Map("map", {displayProjection: new ALKMaps.Projection("EPSG:4326")});
   }
}
```

This will get the map to display and you can put different layers on the map, however the map does not display correctly. @Mike, if you were able to get further than this, will you please comment?

EDIT: The tiles on the image were elongated and not connected. After inspecting the css the main.css, after building, set a global property on the img element to:

```
img { 
   max-width:100%
}
```

The tiles for the map are originally set to 256% for the width. To correct the element, I changed the property for img in the style sheet.

```
show-map {
    img {
       max-width: 256%
    }
}
```

Comment: I just started working on some code related to this again. The best I could do was to create 2 private NPM modules: 1) stores the higher level mapping to the ALK Maps library,  2) stores the .d.ts file.

The 1st NPM module has a dependency on the 2nd and looks at it to get types. (I wound up naming the 2nd "@types/alkmaps" which is technically wrong but since it's a private repo it should be ok. It makes it easier for TypeScript to find the types from that module).